# best way to define default class property having large number of properties

Tags: c#, class, properties

What is the best to define default class properties when you have large number of class properties and the default value of ever property is same.Can we do looping to set the default value in such cases. If yes how can we do that.

```
public class PathologyTest
{
    public string testId { get; set;}
    public string testName { get; set;}
    public string testDate { get; set;}
    public string testType { get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Similarly there are around 150 properties of the class and the default value of every property is "invalid patient".

Currently I am doing  `[System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("invalid patient")]` for each property. Is there any way of looping to set the default value. Please suggest what is the best way?

Comment: `[System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("invalid patient")]` doesn't set properties values; they still have default value of their type

Comment: `DefaultValue` attribute only work with designer. You still need to set the expected default yourself.

Comment: it means I am doing wrong. thanks for the comments guys. so how can I solve my problem. Please help

Comment: You're already typing to create 150 properties, add bit more effort to initialize the values in constructor. No easy way without ugly reflection or something like that.

Comment: Why is testDate a string?

Answer (score 1):

- **C# 5 and earlier**: You have to set them in constructor.
- **C# 6**: You can set default value like `public int X { get; set; } = x;` ([Languages features in C# 6 and VB 14](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status))

Comment: No you are not limited to ctor C# 5 and earlierer.  You can use a private backing variable.

Answer (score 0):

So 150 properties
Someone can look at the code and know what it is doing

```
private string defaultValue = "default value"
private string testID = defaultValue;
public string TestId 
{ 
    get
    {
        return testID;
    }
    set 
    {
        testID = value;
    }
}
```